# How to set an array type variable dynamically in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want to create an array type variable for use in a pipeline, but don't know how to do it.
I want to store this month through December in an array type variable.
For example,
I want to create the following variables in the pipeline to be executed this month;

```
["07","08","09","10","11","12"]
```

Also, next month is like this;

```
["08","09","10","11","12"]
```

Is there any way to create this variable using Synapse's pipeline function?
Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-each activity` and `append variable activity` inside that to create an array variable with values from the current month to December in Synapse pipeline.

- Three variables are defined in synapse pipeline

[image]

1. **StartValue**: This variable stores the current month.
2. **TotalIterationValue**: This variable stores the number of months left in the year.
3. **Array_variable**: This variable is an array that stores the months from the current month to December.

- The variable StartValue and TotalIterationValue are defined using set variable activities.

1. Set variable- Start Value:
   [image]

This activity sets the value of the `StartValue` variable to the current month. It uses the substring function to extract the month from the UTC time and sets it as the value of the variable.
Expression:  `@substring(utcnow(),5,2)`.

2. Set variable - TotalIterationValue:
   [image]
   This activity sets the value of the TotalIterationValue variable to the number of months left in the year. It uses the sub function to subtract the current month from 13 (the total number of months in a year) and sets it as the value of the variable.
   Expression: `@string(sub(13,int(variables('StartValue'))))`

- Then For-each activity is taken and inside **Append variable activity** is taken.

[image]

Expression in items: `@range(0, int(variables('TotalIterationValue')))`

[image]

Expression for `Array_variable`:
`@add(int(variables('StartValue')),item())`

This activity loops through a range of numbers from 0 to the value of `TotalIterationValue` and appends the corresponding month to the Array_variable variable. It uses the add function to add the current iteration number to the StartValue variable and sets it as the value of the Array_variable variable.

```
{
    "name": "PipelineX",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable- Start Value",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "StartValue",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@substring(utcnow(),5,2)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable - TotalIterationValue",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable- Start Value",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "TotalIterationValue",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(sub(13,int(variables('StartValue'))))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable - TotalIterationValue",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0, int(variables('TotalIterationValue')))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "Array_variable",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(int(variables('StartValue')),item())",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "StartValue": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "TotalIterationValue": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Array_variable": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

`Array_variable` will have the values from current month to December.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Aswin's approach, as an alternate , you can try this as well :

```
{
"name": "pipeline38",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "FindCurrentMonth",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "FindCurrentMonth",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@substring(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),5,2)",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Until1",
            "type": "Until",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "FindCurrentMonth",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "expression": {
                    "value": "@equals(variables('TempVar'),'12')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "TempVar",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "appendvariable",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('TempVar')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "TempVar",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "TempVar",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('FindCurrentMonth')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Update month value",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Append variable1",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "FindCurrentMonth",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@{add(int(variables('TempVar')),1)}",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Final Output",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Until1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "finaloutput",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@variables('appendvariable')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "FindCurrentMonth": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "month": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "appendvariable": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "TempVar": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "finaloutput": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

Create these string variables:
`FindCurrentMonth`
`month`
`TempVar`
Create these Array variables:
`appendvariable`
`finaloutput`

- Use set variable activity to fine the currentmonth by using this expression: `@substring(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),5,2)`
- Use until block with expression: `@equals(variables('TempVar'),'12')`
- Inside until, you can set a temp variable with expression: `@variables('FindCurrentMonth')`
- Use Append variable with exp: `@variables('TempVar')`
- Update month value with exp: `@{add(int(variables('TempVar')),1)}`
- Outside until, use another set variable to get the final output: `@variables('appendvariable')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using set variable and append variable inside an until loop.

[image]

Set variable 4 is not required. I only created that to print the values  because append values cannot be seen  in debug mode, you can ignore month2 variable and set variable 4 activity.

[image]

```
{
"name": "Pipeline 1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "start",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@substring(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),5,2)",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Until1",
            "type": "Until",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "expression": {
                    "value": "@equals(variables('start'),'13')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "months",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('start')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Set variable2",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Append variable1",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "start2",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@string(add(int(variables('start')),1))",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Set variable3",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Set variable2",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "start",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('start2')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Set variable4",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Append variable1",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "months2",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('months')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "start": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "months": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "start2": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "months2": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}